# simple c++ function inclusion failure

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I am trying to include a function from another file inside a "main" file. I'm following this paradigm:

http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/18-programs-with-multiple-files/

Here is my main file, digispark.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int send(int argc, char **argv);

int main()
{
    char* on;
    *on = '1';
    char* off;
    *off = '0';
    send(1,&on);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my send.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#if defined WIN
    #include <lusb0_usb.h>    // this is libusb, see http://libusb.sourceforge.net/
#else
    #include <usb.h>        // this is libusb, see http://libusb.sourceforge.net/
#endif

// I've simplified the contents of send for my debugging and your aid, but the
// complicated arguments are a part of the function that will eventually need
// to be here.
int send (int argc, char **argv)
{

    std::cout << "Hello";
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling on Ubuntu 12.10 using the g++ compiler like so:

```
g++ digispark.cpp send.cpp -o digispark
```

It compiles successfully.

However, when I run the program, "Hello" does not come up. Therefore I don't believe the function is being called at all. What am I doing wrong? Any help would be great! Thanks!

## EDIT:

How I dealt with the issue:

```
int send(int argc, char **argv);

int main()
{
    char* on[4];
    on[0] = (char*)"send";
    on[1] = (char*)"1";
    char* off[4];
    off[0] = (char*)"send";
    off[1] = (char*)"0";  
    send(2,on);
    return 0;
}
```

For those of you who were confused as to why I insisted doing this, as I said before, the send function was already built to accept the char** argv (or char* argv[]). My point was to try to mimic that in my main function.

It would have been much more difficult to rewrite the function that actually goes in the send function to take a different type of argument than just to send in what it wanted. Thanks everyone!

So if this helps anyone trying something similar feel free to use it!

Comment: don't use stdio.h and string.h but cstdio and cstring in C++

Comment: Is that an issue with convention or will that actually break my program?

Comment: You might not be ready to use pointers. They're hard, and easy to misuse, as your code shows. Stick to standard C++ library constructs as much as possible.

Comment: Convention yes, breaking your program in some cases. The standard c headers that are used in C++ are made for C++ all are prepended with c and omit the .h

Comment: @ Kerrek SB: You're right; I'm definitely not experienced enough to use them well. But unfortunately, I don't have a choice in the matter at this point. As I wrote in the comments, the real contents of the send function require these more complex structures and I am even less able to alter that function.

Comment: The first four lines in your `main()` should actually crash your program.

Comment: Assuming you fix the other issues, try `std::cout << "Hello" << flush;` ?  I think output is buffered.  In general mixing output via streams and output via stdio is not recommended.

Comment: So I really have an entirely different question is what you guys are saying? Which should be how can I send one char as an array of char arrays to a function?

Comment: Well thanks for the help, at least I have a better idea of where to look into now! Thanks!

Comment: @Marius, The OP got unlucky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not the one you think it is. It's here:

```
char* on;
*on = '1';
```

You declared a `char` pointer, but did not initialize it. Then you dereferenced it. Bang, you're dead. This is what is known as Undefined Behavior. Once you invoke U.B., anything can happen. If you're lucky, it's a crash. But I guess you weren't lucky this time.

Look, if you want to start storing things in memory, you have to allocate that memory first. The best way, as hetepeperfan said, is to just use `std::string` and let that class take care of all the allocating/deallocating for you. But if for some reason you think you have to use C-style strings and pointers, then try this:

```
char on[128]; //or however much room you think you'll need. Don't know? Maybe you shoulda used std::string ...
*on = '1';
*(on+1) = '\0'; //if you're using C-strings, better null terminate.
char off[128];
*off = '0';
*(off+1) = '\0';
send(1,&on);
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I think you try to do something like the following, I tried to make it a bit more in the Style of C++ and prevent the use of pointers since they should not be necessary in the code that you showed.

digispark.cpp

```
#include "send.h"

int main (int argc, char** argv){

    string on  = "1";
    string off = "0";

    send ( on );
    send ( off );

    return 0;
}
```

send.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void send( const std::string& s) {

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

}
```

send.h

```
void send(const std::string& s);
```

Comment: Sorry, you must have missed my comment. The pointers are necessary for the code that will eventually go inside the send function. My question now must be, how do I send a single char to a function as a char**. But that is outside the scope of this particular question. Thank you for your time.